# How to remove Stripe without problems

Tags: stripe

A client stopped using Stripe in Civi (they're not using Civi for payments now) and switched to using Stripe only through their website (bad idea). So I disabled the extension, only to receive emails from Stripe saying that the webhook endpoint was failing. Enabling the extension made that problem go away but now I see error messages in the log like this: "*[message] => Error relating this subscription id (sub_CdRU43deMhfO6T) to the one in civicrm_stripe_subscriptions*"  I have no idea what this means so does anyone have a guide about what to do when removing Stripe from Civi?  It seems there are things to do that I haven't done.

Answer (score 5):

You need to login to the stripe dashboard and disable the webhook.  It has nothing to do with the CiviCRM side.